# Grails 1.3.5: How to configure Datasource.groovy to either connect to MySQL or SQL Server

Tags: grails

The grails application I am developing could run against MySQL or SQL Server. I want to add a new property in application.properties file say
    database.type=MySQL // or it could be SQLSERVER

How do I get this property in Datasource.groovy so that if it is MySQL I connect to MySQL server or it is SQLSERVER I connect to SQL Server?

Is this the correct way to do it? How can I do it?

EDIT: After reading and searching for options I figured the following way explained.
I have created config.properties file in /grails-app/conf/ folder.

```
driverClassName = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
dataSource.url = jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=testDB
dataSource.username = sa
dataSource.password = sa
```

Also updated Config.groovy

```
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:config.properties"]
```

But I get the below error
*Unable to load specified config location classpath:config.properties : class path resource [config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist*

But if use

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:E:/workspace/SpringSource2.3.3/GRAILS_PRO/config.properties"]
```

The application starts up and is able to connect to the database. I don't want to use static file path. What is wrong when using classpath?

Have the same issue for both 'run-app' and 'war' mode i.e. same file does not exist error.

2nd EDIT:

After so much frustration of using classpath and not able to get it to work, I resorted to using environment property. Since server will have CATALINA_HOME defined, I used the below to build the path for external configuration file.

```
def CATALINA_HOME = "CATALINA_HOME"
def CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "db_config.properties"
if(!grails.config.locations || !(grails.config.locations instanceof List)) {
 grails.config.locations = []
}

if(System.getenv(CATALINA_HOME)) {
   def fullPath = System.getenv(CATALINA_HOME) + File.separator + "webapps" + File.separator + "${appName}" + File.separator + "WEB-INF" + File.separator + "classes" + File.separator + CONFIG_FILE_NAME
   grails.config.locations << "file:" + fullPath
} else {
     println "Missing configuration!"
 }
```

The above solution is Tomcat specific. I really would like to see classpath version working!

Thank You.
Regards,
Jay Chandran.

Comment: Have tried placing the property file in root folder, then in /grails-app/conf/ folder still does not work. Get the same error.

Comment: Have also tried what is mentioned here http://little418.com/2010/04/grails-override-configuration-with-properties-file.html

Comment: You can try "classpath:/config.properties". At least, it can be reproduced that it works SOMETIMES (and does NOT one minute later, with another, similar, file).

Comment: Custom config files don't get copied to /target/classes oder /web-app/WEB-INF/classes, even when they're read in and are working. - The offical documentation on that is more than poor. - I've also tried to setup DataSource.groovy, accordingly, - to no avail. - The few samples on the web don't work for me, at all. - This is highly frustrating, and I bet that's not because of my stupidity.

Comment: the custom config file do get copied if you specify it to be copied to classes directory in _Events.groovy as mentioned in the previous link. I will try "classpath:/config.properties" and see what happens.

Comment: "classpath:/config.properties". No luck! Still complains.. can't find file. :(

Comment: Thanks, with "Events.groovy", it's working for me. - If your properties file is not in the (very, very) root of the application, specify "classpath:/grails-app/conf/x.properties", or "classpath:/grails-app/src/groovy/x.properties". - IDEs may display these paths differently from what they are in the file system.

Comment: Does it work for you even in "war" mode? Because everything in grails-app/conf/ goes into classes directory when "war" file is build.

Answer (score 0):

put it in the home directory of the user which is running the instance of tomcat or there should be a .grails directory created for your app , put it under there