# classpath property file in grails app is not being used

Tags: grails, properties, classpath

My problem is that I've put a well-formed properties file in my classpath and told grails to look for the properties file in my classpath, but the properties in the file aren't overriding the existing ones.

In my config.groovy I have the lines:

```
grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
                            "file:./${appName}-config.properties"]

// verified that appName is being used.  It prints out classpath:XXX-config.properties, as expected, where XXX is my appname.
println "grails.config.locations: ${grails.config.locations}"
```

In my XXX-config.properties, I specify a different DB connection URL (this is the one I want to use):

```
dataSource.url=jdbc:postgresql://products.yyyyy.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/mydatabasename
```

Then I put the XXX-config.properties in my classpath and startup tomcat7, but the errors are thrown, saying it can't find my deliberately fake db, meaning the database property did not get overridden.

Now I'm thinking my classpath is wrong, but I do `ps aux | grep tomcat` which tells me that the command line arg for tomcat7 contains " -classpath :/home/jbu/:_other_paths_here_".  Note I put my properties file at /home/jbu/XXX-config.properties.  I am slightly concerned about that leading colon, but it doesn't seem to cause any other problems.

So the classpath dir appears correct, so now I thought maybe my properties file isn't properly formatted, so I added a harded "file:/home/jbu/XXX-config.properties" to my grails.config.locations, and the properties were found and successfully overridden, meaning nothing is wrong with the properties file itself.

I don't have any more ideas here.  Can someone help me out?

---

Sidenote: I modified the CLASSPATH variable for tomcat7 by adding this line to /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh:

```
export CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:/home/jbu/"
```

Comment: Have a look at this project https://github.com/vahidhedayati/kchat - I think you are on grails 2 - this demonstrates and provides example configs as well as tomcat config used to make it do so - hope it helps

Comment: @vahid so you set an env var or pass a property that will specify the file path right?  In my case the tomcat instance isnt under my control and even starts automatically as a higher privilege acct. I cannot easily go and modify tomcat scripts to export new properties every time i want to launch an app like this. However if i can add stuff to the classpath then its a bit easier since i dont have to mess with tomcat configs.

Comment: @vahid yes im on grails 2.4.5. Is this feature supposed to work?  Frankly im a bit fed up with grails just notdoing what i expect and being able to find so little support and answers

Comment: I think all you need to do is just ensure you provide relevant CONFIGLOC path: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/kchat/blob/master/README.md. then in your app you simply refer to that tomcat var and load in config https://github.com/vahidhedayati/kchat/blob/master/grails-app/conf/Config.groovy#L24-L26 - nothing too complex.. I don't think you need to worry about modifying tomcat scripts just the setenv.sh

Comment: the readme refers to `conf/` making it a relative path within tomcat i.e. creating a conf folder within it. If you need it elsewhere simply hardcode physical path there

Comment: @vahid thanks but this is not the type of solution im looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (among with many other things in Grails, it seems) is broken.  Sigh...I'm using grails 2.4.5 so I'm a bit surprised that it has been broken since 1.3.5.

http://jay-chandran.blogspot.com/2010/10/grails-using-external-properties-file.html

[Grails 1.3.5: How to configure Datasource.groovy to either connect to MySQL or SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021217/grails-1-3-5-how-to-configure-datasource-groovy-to-either-connect-to-mysql-or-s)

Comment: Grails 2.4.5 was released over 2 years ago. Commenting on the state of a project when using a version 2 years old is not a fair assessment. There is an external configuration plugin for Grails 3 that provides this feature.

Comment: @JamesKleeh I did very clearly specify what version I'm on.